# How can i use IN condition for DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I need fetch data from DynamoDB by user ids, for it I want to use `IN` condition but I can't find instruction how it use, can you help me? I have some code, how replace `userId = :id1 OR userId = :id2` to `userId IN :ids` ? How set `userIds` in `:ids` ?

```
public List<Data> getByUserIds(List<Long> userIds) {
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(getTableName());
    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
            .withFilterExpression("userId = :id1 OR userId = :id2")
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withNumber(":id1", userIds.get(0))
                    .withNumber(":id2", userIds.get(1))
            );
    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> scanOutcome = table.scan(scanSpec);
    return convertItemToData(scanOutcome.iterator());
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented the solution below

```
public List<HistoricalData> getByUserIdAndLocation(List<Long> userIds) {
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(getTableName());
    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
            .withFilterExpression("userId IN (" + buildInFilterExpression(userIds) + ")")
            .withValueMap(
                    buildValueMap(userIds)
            );
    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> scanOutcome = table.scan(scanSpec);
    return convertItemToHistoricalData(scanOutcome.iterator());
}

private String buildInFilterExpression(List<Long> userIds) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Long id : userIds) {
        builder.append(":user" + id + ",");
    }
    return builder.toString().substring(0, builder.length() - 1);
}

private ValueMap buildValueMap(List<Long> userIds) {
    ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMap();
    for (Long id : userIds) {
        valueMap.withNumber(":user" + id, id);
    }
    return valueMap;
}
```

I think that need to use `valueMap.withList` instead `valueMap.withNumber` but it does not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BatchGetItem API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html) to fetch both users in the same query.

Comment: it not solve my problem, because i can have 1..10...100 condition for `IN` and with `BatchGetIItem` it will look bad

Comment: BatchGetItem doesn't support sort key. so no condition expressions support too